# How to remove all items from Steam store cart?

Tags: steam

Is there a way to empty the whole steam cart at once? I can only find a "Remove" link under each individual item.

[image: Ludicrous amounts of DLC in the steam cart]

I am not really keen to have to remove all 247 DLC for train simulator one by one ...

Comment: Buyimg them all works.

Comment: Well, that would certainly work, but it's a little costly for my taste. Even during a sale.

Comment: 1 804,29 euros on train simulators? Are you rich or something?

Comment: @StarOS He likes trains, okay? XD I like the idea this entire list is made up of train simulators.

Comment: @Prinsig It's not made up of train simulators, it's made up of DLC for Train Simulator. This game is notorious for having a lot of expensive DLC.

Comment: @ardaozkal it doesn't always work. Most of the times I buy stuff, the items are not added to my library within the minute (although I keep the view open). After a while it is added to the library, but also still in my cart, notifying me that I already have the item in my library.

Comment: You're lucky you didn't add 589 DLCs for Rocksmith 2014 like I did earilier this week. Steam client couldn't even load the cart at all.

Comment: How did all the DLCs get added?  I need to look out for these DLC traps and avoid pressing those buttons.

Comment: @nelson there is a "add all to cart" button under the DLC listing on the store page of the game.

Comment: @alexander-revo HAH!  I got you beat, I added 1273 DLCs for Rocksmith 2014 to my cart and now I'm trying to find a way to remove everything because Steam can't load my cart either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of now the Steam cart has a "Remove all items" link by default, so no tricks are necessary anymore.

[image]

---

**Old answer:**

Separate store sessions seem to have separate carts as well, meaning if you add an item within the steam app it will not show up in the cart when you log in with a browser.

Sadly this means Private Pansys answer won't work for the cart in the steam app.

The only way I could find was to clear the cookies of the steam integrated browser:

[image]

This will also clear some other settings, like the age you entered for the +18 games, but IMO that's a small price to pay.

Comment: +1 for thinking out-of-the-box, this should definitely work.

Comment: You could also delete the cookies manually from `AppData\Local\Steam\htmlcache` directory.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but the only caveat is that if you go to the page where the game/DLC is listed, they're still listed as 'in your cart' until you actually put something else into your cart.

Answer (score 11):

[Enhanced Steam](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/) has this feature. To use it, log into Steam from your browser, and install the extension from its homepage. Restart your browser if necessary, and you should see the 'Empty Cart' button on the Steam cart page.

[image]

Comment: This works great if you only use the store with a webbrowser (I already used the extension), but not for the store inside the steam app.

Comment: I thought this project is officially dead?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg [Still looks active](https://github.com/jshackles/Enhanced_Steam), though [the standalone client was discontinued](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/blog/enhanced-steam-standalone-project-discontinued/) the browser extensions are still maintained.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't even load the cart (for example, you added all of the Rocksmith DLC), click on the "Steam" menu and select "Settings", then go to the "Web Browser" tab and click "Delete all browser cookies".

[image]